# How to make a:hover effect show on both lines of an h1 simultaneously?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm converting HTML/CSS files to Wordpress for the first time, and I can't figure out why my two-lined h1 tag at the top of my [homepage](http://tautcopy.com/dev/) won't display the :hover pseudo class for both lines at the same time.

HTML:

```
<h1>
    <a href="http://tautcopy.com/dev/new-post-title-3/" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to Creating a  code block using HTML and CSS">Creating a </a>
    <pre>
        <a href="http://tautcopy.com/dev/new-post-title-3/" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to Creating a  code block using HTML and CSS"> code block using HTML and CSS</a>
    </pre>
</h1>
```

Then I have a CSS rule for `.post-header h1 a:hover`.

I'm sure it's a simple fix, I just have no idea what it is. And Google's not helping at the moment.

Comment: Please include your code to reproduce your problem in your question. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance.

Comment: @Bryce I just did that for you this time. Can you figure out the cause by looking at the code now? You have two separate `<a>` elements.

Comment: You are targetting individual anchor tags change it to `.post-header h1:hover {
  color:rgb(153, 153, 153);
}
` sometimes google cannot help if it doesn't know what is the problem area.. :)

Comment: @bfavaretto I see the two <a> tags, but I'm not sure where they're coming from. Here's what the php looks like: <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

Comment: That's outputting malformed HTML: `<h1><a href="http://tautcopy.com/dev/new-post-title-3/" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to Creating a  code block using HTML and CSS">Creating a <pre> code block using HTML and CSS</a></h1>`. The browser is understanding there are two links.

Comment: Only now I realized that the `<pre>` is part of your title! Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your hover rule should target anchors inside a hovered h1, not hovered anchors directly (since you have two of them):

```
.post-header h1:hover a {
    color: rgb(153, 153, 153);
}
```

---

After the discussion in the comments, I now realize you have malformed HTML. So it may not be interpreted as two links in every browser. I believe the best fix is to keep your current CSS, and fix the underlying problem. You have an unmatched `<pre>` in your anchor; it should be properly HTML-encoded so that `<pre>` so recognized as text, not a tag:

```
Creating a &lt;pre&gt; code block using HTML and CSS
```

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
.post-header h1 a:hover { 
    color: rgb(153, 153, 153);
}
```

into this

```
.post-header h1:hover {
    color: rgb(153, 153, 153);
 }
```

Comment: Bear in mind that `a` elements don't (automatically/by-default) inherit `color` from their parents/ancestors; so that'll probably need to be specified as well.

Comment: thanks! worked like a charm! I can't believe I didn't think of that!

Answer (score 1):

In your css you have the following

```
.post-header h1 a:hover {
  color:rgb(153, 153, 153);
}
```

Change it to

```
.post-header h1:hover {
  color:rgb(153, 153, 153);
}
```

The problem is that you are applying the `:hover` to the `a` element, which probably would work OK, but for some reason your link inside the header is being split into 2 different elements.  I don't know if that was intentional or not.

Is it at all possible that the title is ,

```
Creating a <pre>code block using HTML and CSS</pre>
```

This would cause a problem because the `<pre></pre>` blocks aren't escaped?  I don't know php but there should be some function that will escape this so it is safe to use in html.  Here is what you need to have php output to the file, so that it displays the text `<pre>`

```
Creating a &lt;pre&gt;code block using HTML and CSS&lt;/pre&gt;
```

Answer (score 0):

`.post-header h1 a:hover` works just fine, here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/696bQ/)

```
.post-header h1 a:hover { 
   color: #555;
}
```